# Null Pointer exception error while running the game app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, 2d-games

Currently i'm working in the development of app for some website, but i'm bit crazy on developing game app, so by following the tutorial created an image on Canvas in the 1st level, and in the next level the image has to move for this also coding is given, but when i run the application it gets force close.
here are my codes.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

private Bitmap bmp;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
private int x = 0;  

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
 gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread()
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

           @Override
           public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
               boolean retry = true;
               gameLoopThread.setRunning(false); 
               while (retry) {
                      try {
                            gameLoopThread.join();
                            retry = false;
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      }
               }
           }

        @Override
           public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
               gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
               gameLoopThread.start();
           }


           @Override
           public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                         int width, int height) {
           }

    });

    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    if (x < getWidth() -  bmp.getWidth()) {
        x++;
 }
    canvas.drawBitmap( bmp, x, 10, null);
}
```

Thread class

```
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread{
private GameView view;
private boolean running = false;

public GameLoopThread(GameView view) {
      this.view = view;
}


public void setRunning(boolean run) {
      running = run;
}



@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
@Override

public void run() {
      while (running) {
             Canvas c = null;
             try {
                    c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                           view.onDraw(c);
                    }

             } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                           view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
             }
      }
}
```

logcat result

```
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at com.killthemall.GameView$1.surfaceCreated(GameView.java:40)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:543)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at  android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-21 23:38:26.341: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

> com.killthemall.GameView$1.surfaceCreated(GameView.java:40)

This tells you that a null pointer has happened in the `surfaceCreated` method on line 40.  Looking at that method, the first line does `gameLoopThread.setRunning`, so this can fail with a null pointer `exception if gameLoopThread` is null.

Looking at the code, you aren't initializing `gameLoopThread`, so it has the default value of null.  In the constructor for `GameView` add the line `gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread()`.

Comment: i hv pasted this code gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread() inside Gameview constructor but still getting force close @Jeff Foster